# Socket.io not working with Express 4 without using diffrent port number

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js, express-4

My application works when i specify a port number to socket.io that is diffrent from the server port number. The working code goes as follows:

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var auth = require('./routes/auth.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.set(process.env.PORT || 1337);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ secret: 'mysessionsecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/auth', auth);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

var talk = require('./socket/talk.js')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

This is my talk.js file:

```
var init = function (app){    
    var server = require("http").createServer(app).listen(3000);
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

    var socketioJwt = require("socketio-jwt");
    var jwtSecret = require('../config/jwtSecret');

    console.log("init");

    io.set("authorization", socketioJwt.authorize({
        secret: jwtSecret,
        handshake: true
    }));

    io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
        console.log("connected");
        socket.on("send", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var username = data.username;
            var message = data.message;
            var datetime = data.datetime;

            socket.broadcast.emit("send", data);
        });
        socket.on("busy", function () {
            socket.emit("busy");
            socket.broadcast.emit("busy");
        });
        socket.on("free", function () {
            socket.emit("free");
            socket.broadcast.emit("free");
        });
    });
}

module.exports = init;
```

This is my script tag in index.ejs:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And finally this is my io connect from the client:

```
socket = io("http://localhost:3000/",{
            query: 'token=' + tok
        });
```

This works but the problem is that i want to publish my site to Azure but it is not possible to let a Azure website listen to diffrent ports. At least i think it is not possible.

One of the many things I tried is changing the talk.js file to this:

```
var init = function (app){    
    var server = require("http").createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
...
```

But i it doesn't work. I always get something along the lines of `http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js not found`

If i change the script tag in my index.ejs file to this

```
<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

The socket.io.js file gets loaded but when i connect form te client side i get a continious 404 not found error.

I looked at a lot of solutions online but none of them work. I really don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the `bin/www.js` file being called before `app.js` when using `npm start`. A quick solution is to bypass `www.js`, which is only used to handle some common errors, as it is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222869/3774551).

This [github repo](https://github.com/harijoe/Express.js-Socket.io-Sandbox) is an implementation of this solution and can be used as a starting point for any `Express.js` + `socket.io` application.

Comment: Thx for the awnser! I currently fixed it by using another node.js cloud server and by developing in WebStorm instead of Visual Studio. I still not sure why that worked :p. Anyway I'll definitely try this.