# How to listen to socket events and http post ? node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am working on node js server which use socket io.

```
var express = require('express') 
app = express.createServer();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token");
    next();
 });
app.get("/", function(req, res) {res.send('admin')});
```

i need to listen to post request with json body so i've added these lines:

```
app.post('/testPost',function(req,res){

       console.log("post json : " + req.body );
});
```

but i am receiving undefined request body. that because i should add :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
 }));
```

but now after adding bodyParser.json() the socket io doesn't connect !

what should i do ? how to ask node js to use **bodyParser.urlencoded** just with ***/testPost route*** ?

Comment: see this so http://stackoverflow.com/a/33596348/4466350

Comment: @mh-cbon thank you for your comment . but that didn't help